# modal window problem

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I am using colorbox a jquery plugin to emulate modal window which is not able to overlay flash movies and youtube video.

I have experimented with the z-index but nothing seems working.

Please enlighten me on this.
thnx in advance

Comment: can you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash movies should have their wmode parameter set to transparent. If not, they get the highest z-index slot. transparent put them at the default page level.

Comment: how to set wmode to transparent

Comment: Does this help: http://joshuaink2006.johnoxton.co.uk/blog/82/flash-content-and-z-index ?

Comment: Add this in your embed/object code for the flash <param name="wmode" value="transparent">